# jQuery search input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got this HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Type country name" class="Cinp">
<div class="contres"></div>
```

And this jQuery code:

```
var country_list=  ["Argentina","Armenia","Aruba","Australia","Austria","Azerbaijan"];
var results = [];
var selected= [];

$(".Cinp").keyup(function(e) {
    var value=$(this).val();

    if (e.which >= 65 && e.which <= 90 || e.which==8) {
        if (value.length!=0) {
            function filter(letter) {
                var len = country_list.length;
                var i = 0;

                while(i < len) {
                    if (country_list[i].indexOf(letter) == 0 || country_list[i].indexOf(letter.toUpperCase()) == 0 ) {
                        results.push(country_list[i]);
                        $(".contres").append(country_list[i]);
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So it works perfectly when I type only first letter, but when I type `Az` it should return `Azerbaijan` only but it returns all countries that start with `a`.

Comment: All depends on how are you calling the filter function. From where is the filter function getting its parameter? I mean, where are you getting 'Letter' from?

Comment: From input's value @VinodBhavnani

Comment: What happens if you start typing a, then change your mind, delete and start typing d? I think you will see countries starting with both a and d. I think it's because you are never clearing the results list, only adding to it. You need to clear it each time the user presses a key and re-create it it. Otherwise all the previous results will still be there.

Comment: Yeah.I already got the answer:) @ADyson

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/6kobb2dm/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            $(".contres").clear(); /// whether need that?

             while(i < len) {
                 if (country_list[i].indexOf(letter) == 0 || country_list[i].indexOf(letter.toUpperCase()) == 0 ){
                    results.push(country_list[i]);
                    $(".contres").append(country_list[i]);
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }
```